# Can I use end=' ' in input() to take an input with spaces but not a new line?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, input

I want the input to be like

```
2 3 4 5
```

and not like

```
2
3
4
5
```

Is there any way to do it by adding `end=''` or some other way in the `input()` function?

This is part of a recursive function called `makearray()`. I want it to take spaced inputs and not on new lines.

```
l = int(float(input("Enter number in array 1:"end='')))  
if (l > 0):
    global p
    p = np.append(p, l * l)
else:
    pass
makearray(b - 1)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem. Try the following `l = list(map(int, input("Enter the values with spaces between them: ").split()))`. It will create the list of entered values

Comment: "I want the input to be 2 3 4 5 and not 2 3 4 5"
What do you mean?
Can you give more details about what do you want, please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.